# Stderr of piped shell scripts isn't always displayed

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, pipe, stderr

I piped my own shell scripts for some testing and accidentally noticed something strange. Namely, the stderr of those piped processes isn't always displayed on the screen.

I simplified the scripts and here's my session with bash:

```
$ cat file1
echo stdout
echo stderr 1>&2
$ cat file2
echo stdout2
echo stderr2 1>&2
$ cat file3
echo stdout3
echo stderr3 1>&2

$ ./file1 | ./file2 | ./file3
stderr2
stderr
stdout3
stderr3

$ ./file1 | ./file2 | ./file3
stderr
stdout3
stderr3

$ ./file1 | ./file2 | ./file3
stderr2
stdout3
stderr3
```

I know that the stdout of the first two scripts is lost, since file3 doesn't read anything, but it doesn't matter here.

What's happening with the `stderr2` and `stderr` outputs in the 2nd and 3rd case, respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ooh, a race condition!  There are a few things going on here behind the scenes to produce this effect.

First, if a process tries to write to a pipe whose other end has been closed, that process receives a `SIGPIPE` signal.  By default, this ends the process.  Why would you want this?  If you run `cat my_huge_file | head -3`, you'll only see the first three lines of the file, and because of the signaling mechanism, `cat` knows to stop after those three lines.  Without it, it would read the whole file.

Second, all processes in a pipeline run in parallel, and which process will finish first is unpredictable.  When a process ends, all of its file descriptors are closed -- including the read ends of any pipes.

So what's happening is that sometimes, for example, `file3` finishes completely before `file2` has written to its stdout.  Then, when `file2` does try to write, it gets `SIGPIPE`, and quits without reaching the `echo stderr2` line.  But then other times, `file2` manages to write to stdout before `file3` completes, and in this case it gets to continue.